# merise and uml can they coexist in a real project?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, uml

In a real world project when you have to work with object oriented modeling and database modeling to create some kind of Information system, be it a huge website or a desktop application.

- can u work with both merise and UML?
- or just one modeling system is enough?
- in this case which one to use?
- in the first case who come first Merise or UML ?
- and how would you passe from one too another ?

for exemple the Project consist off a java EE business server and a java desktop applciation, in other word a 3tires system.

Comment: Upvotes for a novel topic and insightful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML and Merise are both organizational toolboxes for software development, so in that respect there's nothing fundamentally wrong about using one or another, as it will/should only be used to help formalizing some aspects of your development decisions (use cases, class diagrams, etc.). In terms of expressivity, if I remember well Merise has some database modeling capabilities that you'll find lacking in UML, while UML has use case modeling, sequence diagrams that you won't find (if I remember well) in Merise. All in all, I would say that UML provides some more tools for high-level software development concepts (conceptual/organizational dimensions), while Merise is a bit more organizational/operational.

That said, everything should come down to these questions/rationale that should guide your final choice:

- what it the culture of your team? As far as I know, Merise is a development process that didn't really catch up outside of France, and it is being slowly abandoned in favor of UML. Chances are, if you're in a younger team, most developers should have a few UML notions.
- if you're in a team with both UML/Merise cultures, is there really a benefit to using both languages? While most concepts should map between both approaches (it's fairly easy **once you master both**), it will require everyone to make the effort of mentally translating those concepts between each development diagram/phase. Will that really be worth the while?
- there's one final aspect that'll make UML shine: tooling. While I'm pretty sure there's a few Merise IDEs around, you'll find a profusion of tools for editing UML diagrams comfortably (e.g., Visio or [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) on the PC, Omigraffle on the Mac, portable solutions such as [Papyrus](http://www.papyrusuml.org/) (for Eclipse) or Gentleware's [Poseidon](http://www.gentleware.com/uml-software-community-edition.html). Last thing you'd want is sharing basic drawings or PDFs to explain your design choices.

Comment: thanks for the answer. actually it a school project and i do have some basic knowledge about both models. my project is about EMR in a 3tiers architect with java EE, that said can model my EJB classes JPA .. using UML then using Merise to Model the database ? or those UML do the JOB ?

Comment: Well if in the end you need to provide a report for your project, you should certainly stick to one model, following common industry practices. My personal preference would go to plain UML for modeling use cases, class diagrams and sequence diagrams. Then I would use UML's data modeling profile (you'll find a nice introduction [there](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/umlDataModelingProfile.html) to detail how the project's classes are actually mapped to the relational database (there's also guide on this [here](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html).

Comment: This will provide you with nice and clean diagrams for detailing concepts and behaviours, and a decent representation of the database level.

Comment: thanks that really helpful, one last question does use case , class diagrams and sequence diagrams modeling apply to EJB session beans  and entity ? or do they have other diagrams ?

Comment: [Component diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html) are very well suited to representing the organization of EJB sessions and entities. Class diagrams would be more suited to representing the finer details of your classes (attributes, methods etc.), while sequence diagrams will help you describe the behaviour of your system.